# How to use dropwizard metrics for asynchronous callback

Tags: cassandra, dropwizard, cassandra-3.0, codahale-metrics

I want to use dropwizard metrics for asynchronous callback in my application.I am inserting records in cassandra asychrounously.

I have a list of queries (bound statemets) being executed asnchronously. I have added a callback to track onSuccess() and onFailure() to my asynchronous execution.
(A semaphore is also there just to throttle number of asynchronous insert query execution)

Now, I want correctly implement metric so that I can measure or monitor the following:

1. Number of insert request/queries sent per minute.
2. Number of request executed succesfully
3. Number of response received after successful insertion (successcount,success rate per minuite)
4. Number of response received after failure insertion (failureCount,failure rate per minuite)

Below is my code snippet for which I need to include the metrics.Please help.

```
    final Semaphore queryPermits= new Semaphore(100);
public List<ListenableFuture<ResultSet>> sendAsyncQueries(List<BoundStatement> boundStatements) throws CqlException, AdapterException {
    List<ListenableFuture<ResultSet>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    final ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    for (BoundStatement boundStatement : boundStatements) {
        try {
            queryPermits.acquire();//Sempahore to throttle cassandra insert
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.error("InterruptedException while acquire permit for asynchronous insertion ",e);
        }
        try {
            final ListenableFuture<ResultSet> resultSetFuture = executeAsynchronously(boundStatement, ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
            Futures.addCallback(resultSetFuture,
                    new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(ResultSet result) {
                            LOG.debug("Inserted cassandra row ");
                            queryPermits.release();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                            LOG.error("Error while inserting inCassandra ");
                            queryPermits.release();
                        }
                    },
                    executor
            );
            futures.add(resultSetFuture);
        }catch(AdapterException e){
            queryPermits.release();
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return  futures;
}
```

Comment: I think you just require a meter and tick it whenever you get your callback? By the way you can use a `RateLimiter` by guava to limit the amount of requests you would like to submit.